# Showing/hiding li elements that have a different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items that have subcategories, none of the `<li>` elements have a class. The links that aren't subcategories will be just `<a>` but the subcategories will be `<a class="subcategory">` -- If I have something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Arts</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Paintings</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Watercolors</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Impressionist</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Colors</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Red</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Blue</a>
</li>
```

Can I make only red/blue show up when "Colors" is moused over and the same for paintings? Trying to use jquery and I've come up with the code that makes **all** the subcategories show up when I mouse over any of the links, but that's not quite what I want.

Edit: Here's the code I tried (really simple):

```
$('li a').mouseover(function(){ $('li a.subcategory').show();});
```

and

```
$('li a').mouseleave(function(){ $('li a.subcategory').hide();});
```

Would it be better to next the subcategories in a separate list?

Comment: please show us the code you tried

Comment: "...I've come up with the code..." - show us!

Comment: Modified the post, sorry about that!

Comment: `but the subcategories will be <li class="subcategory">` <-- Actually, you have the class inside `<a>`. Which is it?

Comment: @kei Made the edit to specify the class was in the `a` tag.

Comment: Assign a class to each sub-category that matches the ID of the heading. Then, if any `<li>` is hovered that lacks an ID, hide all the classes. **See my answer for a demo.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATED

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/W8w7t/1/)

```
$("li").has("a.subcategory").hide();
$("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").hover(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).nextUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").hide();
});
$("li:has('a.subcategory')").hover(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").andSelf().show();
    $(this).prevUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).nextUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").andSelf().hide();
    $(this).prevUntil("li:not(:has('a.subcategory'))").hide();
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Is there an option I could use to make the hover out a little slower so users will be able to click on the subcategories easier?

Comment: @sp33k3rph433k - Perhaps kei can re-code his (very elegant! +1) solution to handle that. Or, see my solution since it handles that condition.

Comment: You can make this slower by adding a number in milliseconds to the show or hide calls, like ".show(100);"

Answer (score 3):

I would put the subcategories inside the category, something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Colors</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Red</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Blue</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Then you could use something like this with jquery:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  $(this).children( ".subcategory" ).css( "display", "block" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It you want to keep the same classes but have some behave differently-
Your going to want to set ids on them and have them act differently according to the id on
[mouseOver()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseover.asp) If you wanted to go the javascript route you could also display these as objects and use there id's to help you differentiate what the user is viewing... Ex.

var menu =

[

{
        "id" : "1" ,
        "name" : "GSXR"
    },

```
{
    "id" : "2" ,
    "name" : "CBR"
},
{
    "id" : "3" ,
    "name" : "ZX"
},
{
    "id" : "4" ,
    "name" : "YZF-R"
},
{
    "id" : "5" ,
    "name" : "RC-8"
}
```

];
function renderMenu()

{
    var myUL = document.getElementById('menu');

```
var html = '';

for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
{
    html += '<li><a id="'+menu[i].id+'"onclick="display(id)" href="#">'+menu[i].name+'</a></li>';
}

myUL.innerHTML = html;
```

}

This is how ive built out menus when i needed to know user click or hover... 
Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the attributes for each li element, I would suggest the following:

- Assign the Headings an appropriate ID (eg. Paintings = `id="paintings"`)
- Assign the sub-headings the identical name, as a class (eg. `class="paintings"`)
- Use jQuery to toggle the visibility

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4W7/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Arts</a></li>
<li id="paintings"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Paintings</a></li>
<li class="paintings"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Watercolors</a></li>
<li class="paintings"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Impressionist</a></li>
<li id="colors"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Colors</a></li>
<li class="colors"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Red</a></li>
<li class="colors"><a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory">Blue</a></li>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var xid;
$('#paintings').hover(
    function() {
        $('.colors').hide();
        xid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.'+xid).show();
    }
);
$('#colors').hover(
    function() {
        $('.paintings').hide();
        xid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.'+xid).show();
    }
);
$('li').mouseover(function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
        $('.paintings').hide();
        $('.colors').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would add an extra class to identify to which category the item belongs and also use a data-related to control it, something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wnHuN/)

```
<li>
<a href="/en/explore/in/arts">Arts</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" data-related="paitings">Paintings</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory paitings">Watercolors</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory paitings">Impressionist</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" data-related="colors">Colors</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory colors">Red</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/en/explore/in/arts" class="subcategory colors">Blue</a>
</li>
```

then i would hide all of the subcategories and on hover display only those that have the same class as the hovered link in the data-related

```
$(function(){    
    //Hide all of the subcategories
    $(".subcategory").parent("li").hide();

    //Assign hover event only to the links that don't have a class
    $("li a").not("[class]").hover(function(){
        $("." + $(this).data("related")).parent("li").show();
    });
});
```